# Changing current-video while playing in Playbin2 makes the video stop

Tags: gstreamer, playbin2

I have a playbin2 pipeline playing a video file with multiple tracks. I can change the currently playing track by setting the `current-video` property:

```
current-video       : Currently playing video stream (-1 = auto)
                      flags: readable, writable
                      Integer. Range: -1 - 2147483647 Default: -1
```

However, once I set this, the video hangs and then eventually turns gray. The audio keeps playing. A coworker suggested that flushing the pipeline might fix it, but the only way to do that seems to be seeking to the current position with `GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH`. Using the seek does work, but it seems messy:

```
g_object_set(m_playBin, "current-video", video, NULL);
GstClockTime = getCurrentTime();
gst_element_seek(m_playBin, m_player->rate(),
        GST_FORMAT_TIME,
        (GstSeekFlags)(GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_ACCURATE),
        GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, clockTime,
        GST_SEEK_TYPE_NONE, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE)
```

Am I doing something wrong when I set the `current-video`? Is there a simpler way to flush the pipeline?

Note: I'm using an Ogg Theora file for testing since it was easy to build, so I'm not sure if this problem shows up in other formats.